# How to animate along with device rotation on iOS 7

Tags: animation, ios7, ios8, rotation

I want to do some animation along with device rotation. On iOS 8, I can do this:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // My custom animation
    } completion:nil];
}
```

But this method is not available on iOS 7. I tried to do the similar thing as follows:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Custom animations
    } completion:nil];
}
```

But the self.transitionCoordinator object is nil here. Does anyone know how to achieve the same effect on iOS 7?

I'm not sure if I just call this animateAlongsideTransition method in the wrong place or even if animateAlongsideTransition is the right method to call. So any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have found an answer for my own question. For those who are also wondering the same thing, **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation** method is the one to use.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        // Custom animations
    }];
}
```

And it looks like the custom animation has to be here. If I move the animation block to the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method, it won't work.